# Are there any Pokemon that get smaller when they evolve?

Tags: pokemon-series

Most Pokemon get physically larger when they evolve. For example, the tiny Bulbasaur turns into the slightly larger Ivysaur, who then turns into the monstrous Venusaur.

[image]

Are there any Pokemon that instead become smaller when they evolve?

Answer (score 35):

There are a few cases of Pokémon getting shorter when they evolve.

- Haunter (1.6 m) into Gengar (1.5 m)
- Porygon (0.8 m) into Porygon2 (0.6 m)
- Dragonair (4.0 m) into Dragonite (2.2 m)
- Gloom (0.8 m) into Bellossom (0.4 m)
- Cosmog (0.2 m) into Cosmoem (0.1 m)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116907/discussion-on-answer-by-wrigglenite-are-there-any-pokemon-that-get-smaller-when).

Comment: Just because I was curious, I ran a wikidata query to find all combinations based on data entered there. It finds Porygon, Dragonair and Gloom. https://w.wiki/pHr Wikidata believes Gengar to be 190.5 cm (no real source) and Cosmog has no height there, so is automatically excluded.

Answer (score 9):

Evolution reduces Kadabra's mass from 56.5 kg to 48.0 kg. Mega Alakazam is the same mass, but is shorter than Kadabra (1.2 m vs. 1.3 m; "base" Alakazam is 1.5 m).