# Which Pokemon weigh less or the same when they evolve?

Tags: pokemon-series

Most Pokemon gain weight (and height) when they evolve. There are some exceptions to this, for example Gloom to Bellossom, and Cosmeom to either Solgaleo or Lunala. Which Pokemon lose weight or retain their weight when evolving?

There are some lists online, but they are all incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pokemon that lose weight when they evolve are:

- Gloom (29 lbs / 8.6 kg) to Bellossom (12.8 lbs / 5.8 kg)
- Kadabra (124.6 lbs / 56.5 kg) to Alakazam (105.8 lbs / 48.0 kg). Alakazam's weight does not change when it Mega Evolves
- Porygon (80.5 lbs / 36.5 kg) to Porygon2 (71.6 lbs / 32.5 kg). Porygon-Z has weight in between the two at 75.0 lbs / 34.0 kg
- Though not strictly an evolution, Mewtwo's weight (269.0 lbs / 122.0kg) decreases when Mega Evolving to Mega Mewtwo Y (72.8 lbs / 33.0 kg)
- Galarian Corsola (1.1 lbs / 0.5 kg) to Cursola (0.9 lbs / 0.4 kg). Normal Corsola weighs more than both of them (11.0 lbs / 5.0 kg)
- Though not strictly an evolution, Nincada (12.1 lbs / 5.5 kg) to Shedninja (2.6 lbs / 1.2 kg)
- Clamperl (115.7 lbs / 52.5 kg) to either Huntail (59.5 lbs / 27.0 kg) or Gorebyss (49.8 lbs / 22.6 kg)
- Shelgon (243.6 lbs / 110.5 kg ) to Salamence (226.2 lbs / 102.6 kg)
- Gligar (142.9 lbs / 64.8 kg) to Gliscor (93.7 lb / 42.5 kg). This was the one that surprised me the most.
- Though not an evolution, Phione (6.8 lbs / 3.1 kg) weighs more than Manaphy (3.1 lbs / 1.4 kg)
- Type Null (255.7 lbs / 120.5 kg) to Silvally (221.6 lbs / 100.5 kg)
- Cosmeom (2204.4 lbs / 999.9 kg) to Solgaleo (507.1 lbs / 230.kg) or Lunala (264.6 lbs / 120.0 kg)

Pokemon that remain the same weight:

- Gastly (0.2 lbs / 0.1 kg) to Haunter

Credit goes to Z9. for starting this list. This was sourced by manually going through the Pokemon list on Bulbapedia.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pokemon that lose weight:

- **Gloom** (29 lbs / 8.6 kg) → **Bellossom** (12.8 lbs / 5.8 kg)
- **Porygon** (80.5 lbs. / 36.5 kg) → **Porygon2** (71.6 lbs. / 32.5 kg)
- **Shelgon** (243.6 lbs. / 110.5 kg ) → **Salamence** (226.2 lbs. / 102.6 kg) (Thanks to [Sumurai8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/68284/sumurai8) & [MBorg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/219593/mborg))
- **Nincada** (12.1 lbs. / 5.5 kg) → **Shedninja** (2.6 lbs. / 1.2 kg)

#### Pokemon that lose height:

- **Gloom** (2'7" / 80cm) to **Bellossom** (1'4" / 40cm)
- **Dragonair** (13'01" / 4m long) → **Dragonite** (7'03" / 2.2m tall)
- **Porygon** (2'07" / 80cm) → **Porygon2** (2'00" / 60cm)
- **Haunter** (5'03" / 1.6 m) → **Gengar** (4'11" / 1.5 m)

#### Notes

- Gengar (89.3 lbs. / 40.5 kg ) weighs more than Haunter (0.2 lbs. / 0.1 kg) (Thanks [MBorg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/219593/mborg))
- Porygon2 gains some of the weight back for Porygon Z.
- Nincada to Shedninja loses about 10 lbs, but there are extenuating circumstances.
- This list is most likely incomplete: please edit if you know others

#### Sources:

- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/37us68/which_pokemon_get_smaller_when_they_evolve/crpyvjj)
- [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net)

Comment: about nincada example, it's not totally true, because when nincada evolves only in ninjask if you have a full team of 6 pokemons on you; shedninja is a "bonus" pokemon if you have an empty room available, so you can't really consider him as a real evolution

Comment: FYI the question is only asking for weight. There's another question for height: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378516/are-there-any-pokemon-that-get-smaller-when-they-evolve